# org.json.simple: Why does JSONParser.parse() return an Object and not a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, org.json

Just for curiosity's sake, why is it that the Simple-JSON parser doesn't return a JSONObject?

Answer (score 1):

After examining the code, it hit me: the JSONParser, like many parsers, is a recursive function that returns tree nodes and subtrees after it builds them. During the parse, the return value could be a JSON String, Number, Array, or Object, hence the broadest base type (Object) must be used for the return type.